# Adding click event handler to a Graphics oval or rectangle

Tags: java, event-handling, awt, java-2d

I am designing a simple game on cognitive science Multiple objects tracking in which I have to  alternate the color of a drawn oval when clicked. i.e Yellow to RED and vice versa.How to implement it.

```
     public void draw(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(color);
      g.fillOval((int)(x - radius), (int)(y - radius), (int)(2 * radius),
            (int)(2 * radius));


   }


balls[0] = new Ball(100, 410, 25, 3, 34, 
Color.YELLOW);



private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener
        {


            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {


            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to add an actioneventlistener

Comment: @PhilippSander can you help me? how to add an event listner to a drawn shape

Comment: show us what you've tried to change the color onclick

Comment: @PhilippSander I have edited my question with code please check

Comment: you should really ready a tutorial first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.